# How to delete rows using 2 different columns as condition in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, sql-delete

My table is something like this:

```
Name       Order      Goods          Date
------------------------------------------------
Michael     1         Shoes          2019/04/05
Michael     2         Groceries      2019/05/28
Michael     3         Caps           2019/03/02
Lucas       4         Shoes          2019/02/30
Lucas       5         Caps           2019/03/31
Mary        6         Shoes          2018/04/22 
Mary        7         Shoes          2018/03/25
Mary        8         Groceries      2017/08/22
Mary        9         Caps           2019/01/01
```

How to define a query so that I can delete rows obeying the following conditions:

1. First and foremost I want to group everything by the `Name` column
2. `Shoes` is my reference. I need to check If any customer has bought "Shoes" and will keep any other Goods registered if and only if the buying date is earlier than the "Shoes" buying date of that customer (grouped by the Name column) (i.e if any good other than Shoes has been bought after the Shoes buying date, this any other good row will be deleted)
3. I keep only the first buying date of Shoes to compare. Newer dates are deleted too. Only the first one (older one) is kept.

So, I will have a table like below:

```
Michael 1 Shoes      2019/04/05
Michael 3 Caps       2019/03/02
Lucas   4 Shoes      2019/02/30
Mary    7 Shoes      2018/03/25
Mary    8 Groceries  2017/08/22
```

Thank you

Comment: SIde note: `2019/02/30` is not a valid date.

Comment: it's nice to have sample and expected answer, but this isnt a 'hey you, write me a query now!' site. wouldnti t be good if we can start from your code? like what have you tried

Comment: Sorry for giving you that impression. I ended up here asking for help after 6 hours of tryouts using SQL queries and zillions of Pandas.DF alternatives. Every and each of them ended up as failures. I will keep your advice in mind on any other visit to this place.

Comment: What if the customer never buys shoes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join an aggregate query that computes the first date when each customer ordered shoes, and use that information to filter the rows to delete:

```
delete t
from mytable t
inner join (
    select name, min(date) min_date 
    from mytable 
    where goods = 'Shoes' 
    group by name
) t1 on t.name = t1.name and t.date > t1.min_date
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=104d0104e366b5ac50b97d549af4cac6)**:

```
Name    | OrderID | Goods     | Date      
:------ | ------: | :-------- | :---------
Michael |       1 | Shoes     | 2019-04-05
Michael |       3 | Caps      | 2019-03-02
Lucas   |       4 | Shoes     | 2019-02-28
Mary    |       7 | Shoes     | 2018-03-25
Mary    |       8 | Groceries | 2017-08-22
```

Comment: Thank you so much, GMB!